# Postgres JOIN with unnest

Tags: database, postgresql, join, relation, unnest

Assume I have following tables:

```
table: followers_arrays

   id   |  array
--------+---------
    1   | {3,4,5}


table: small_profiles

   id   | username |  pic    
--------+----------+-------
    3   |   aaaa   | abcd
    4   |   bbbb   | abcd
    5   |   cccc   | abcd
```

I would like to print *followers_array* with populated data from *small_profiles* using simple JOINs.

At first, I'm using *unnest* function like this:

```
SELECT id, unnest(followers_array) AS elem FROM followers_arrays
```

And it gives me about right result:

```
   id   |  elem  
--------+--------
    1   |    3
    1   |    4
    1   |    5
```

Now, from my understanding I just need to join this data to *small_profiles* ON *small_profiles.id* key like this:

```
SELECT id, unnest(followers_array) AS elem 
FROM followers_arrays 
JOIN small_profiles ON small_profiles.instagram_id = elem
```

However it seems that during JOIN, column *elem* is not created yet because I get following error:
*ERROR:  column "elem" does not exist*

Any thoughts how should I rearrange my query?
Thanks

Comment: query step is 1- from ..... 2- where .... 3- group by .... 4- select ...... So when you use alias 'elem' after select didn't work in join

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is bad design but here is your answer:

```
select f.id, f.follower, s.username, s.pic
from
    (
        select id, unnest("array") as follower
        from followers_arrays
    ) f
    inner join
    small_profiles s on f.follower = s.id
```

Comment: Works! Could you please tell me why it's bad design?

Comment: @Rafal There is no reason to have an array at that. Plain normalization would work much better.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Why would plain normalization work better?

Comment: Plain Normalization will work more efficiently in most cases, but that doesn't mean that this is bad design or that there are no use cases for this.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use Common Table Expressions over Subqueries:

```
WITH unnested_arr_1 AS (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) array_1_item
)
,unnested_arr_2 AS (
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[2, 3, 4]) array_2_item
)
SELECT  *
FROM    unnested_arr_1 arr1
    FULL OUTER JOIN unnested_arr_2 arr2 ON arr1.array_1_item=arr2.array_2_item
```

produces:

```
array_1_item |array_2_item |
-------------|-------------|
1            |[NULL]       |
2            |2            |
3            |3            |
[NULL]       |4            |
```

If joining only unnested arrays, then the above query can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   unnest(
    ARRAY[1, 2, 3]
   ,ARRAY[2, 3, 4]
) as U(array_1_item , array_2_item );
```

Comment: CTE is not a substitute of sub-query. There are some performance concerns regarding using it - https://thoughtbot.com/blog/advanced-postgres-performance-tips#common-table-expressions-and-subqueries

Answer (score 4):

The answers above are functionally correct. I would recommend something like this, it is more compact and simpler:

```
SELECT f.id, sp.username, sp.pic
FROM followers_arrays fa
     CROSS JOIN unnest(fa.array) f(id)
     JOIN small_profiles sp ON sp.id = f.id;
```

I generally recommend against using CTE as it can be a barrier for the query planner. This data set is so small that it does not matter, but a larger dataset could be problematic. I also try to avoid sub-queries unless it can reduce the cartesian row set.