# In PostgreSQL: how to transform an array field containing FKs to array of names from referenced table?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

My database has a table of Products, like so:

```
PRODUCTS
----------------------------
 id | name      | suppliers
----------------------------
  1 | widget    | {1,2}
  2 | gizmo     | {1}
  3 | geegaw    | {3}
  4 | tchotchke | null
```

The `suppliers` column contains an array (`numeric[]`) of IDs belonging to a table of suppliers:

```
SUPPLIERS
------------
 id | name 
------------
  1 | alpha
  2 | beta
  3 | gamma
```

How can I write a query that will return the contents of `PRODUCTS` except with an array of supplier names instead of supplier ID numbers?  Result should look like this:

```
-----------------------------------
 id | name      | suppliers
-----------------------------------
  1 | widget    | {'alpha','beta'}
  2 | gizmo     | {'alpha'}
  3 | geegaw    | {'gamma'}
  4 | tchotchke | null
```

Succinct and efficient methods would be preferred, but readability/understandability are also nice.

**Edit**: This isn't a duplicate of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466823/postgres-join-with-unnest), although that question does involve the `unnest` operation, it doesn't re-aggregate the result.  The answer to this question makes a new contribution to the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres JOIN with unnest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466823/postgres-join-with-unnest).  The accepted answer in the duplicate link should work for you.

Comment: how do you maintain the consistence of the column `suppliers`? I would recommend to create a satellite table for `suppliers` and create a constraint to the `products` table (1 to N relationship).

Comment: @JimJones these tables are actually two dimensions in a star-schema datamart, so they are not normalized according to 3NF.  Referential integrity is managed in the source system from which the data is ETL'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, array_agg(s.Name) as Suppliers 
from Products t1 
left join lateral (
select unnest(suppliers) as supplierId from myProducts t2 
where t1.id = t2.id) as t on true
left join Suppliers s on s.Id = t.supplierID
group by t1.id, t1.name;
```

What was I thinking. Here is a better version:

```
select p.id, p.name, array_agg(s.Name) as Suppliers
from (select *,unnest(suppliers) as supplierId from Products) p 
left join Suppliers s on s.Id = p.supplierID
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track.  I just realized my data also contains null rows (no suppliers) and have edited the question accordingly.  Would your query work in that case if we just change `inner join` to a `left join`?  Would the result be a null column or an empty array?

Comment: You can then use the first one with left join. It would return {NULL}.

Comment: Second one works with left join also.  If you want to update your answer with that, it would then match the question and I can mark it accepted.